# Zend_DB_Select - How to write this SQL Statement

Tags: sql, zend-framework, zend-db

Good Morning,

i have some Trouble with the Zend Framework and Zend_DB_Select, i want to use
this (Working) SQL Statement as Zend DB Select Statement :

```
select
  oslang
from
  oslang, os
where
  oslang.oslang_id = os.oslang_id and
  ossubversion_id = 1
```

I have tryed to following but it doenst work :

```
try {
        $select = $this->_db->select()
             ->from('OSLANG')
             ->from('OS')
             ->where("OSLANG.OSLANG_ID = OS.OSLANG_ID")
             ->where("OSSUBVERSION_ID = ?", $subVersionId);
        $results = $select->query()->fetchAll();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_logException($e);
        $results = array();
    }
```

it must be possible that more than one OS is associated with an OSLANG_ID

Does someone has an nice idea where my error is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        $select = $this->_db->select()
             ->from('OSLANG')
             ->join('OS',"OSLANG.OSLANG_ID = OS.OSLANG_ID")
             ->where("OSSUBVERSION_ID = ?", $subVersionId);
        $results = $select->query()->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Not 100% ;-) It must be possible to select from OS all Records associated with the OSLANG_ID. There are X Operating Systems associated to the same OSLANG_ID

horrible i now ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM x, y
```

is equal to

```
SELECT * FROM x CROSS JOIN y
```

So, try using **joinCross()** method. According to its PHPDoc:

> The $name and $cols parameters follow
>   the same logic as described in the
>   from() method.

It 'll be something like that:

```
    $select = $this->_db->select()
         ->from('OSLANG')
         ->joinCross('OS')
         ->where("OSLANG.OSLANG_ID = OS.OSLANG_ID")
         ->where("OSSUBVERSION_ID = ?", $subVersionId);
    $results = $select->query()->fetchAll();
```

---

Note, if you are using MySQL, CROSS JOIN is equal to INNER JOIN:

> In MySQL, CROSS JOIN is a syntactic
>   equivalent to INNER JOIN (they can
>   replace each other). In standard SQL,
>   they are not equivalent. ([MySQL 5.1
>   Reference Manual :: JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html))

The only difference is that:

> INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause,
>   CROSS JOIN is used otherwise

So in MySQL you can omit using INNER or CROSS keywords, the syntax is:

> … tableReference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN
>   tableFactor [joinCondition] …